# Problems sending/handling signals across two processes on same computer - C programming

Tags: c, signals, kill, interprocess

I'm having trouble handling signals between two process I have running on my computer. scheduler.c is sending the signals and producer.c receiving them. The producer is supposed to print "Printing n" where n is incremented by one each time a SIGUSR1 is received. I have tried using both signal and sigaction to handle the signals but neither is working for me.

scheduler.c:

```
/*
 * scheduler.c
 */


#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n = 1;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 0; // This variable will be used for the switch later

    // Check to ensure correct number of command line arguments
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage error. Wrong number of arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Grab PID of producer.c
    int producer_pid = atoi(argv[1]);       

    while(1){
        printf("Choose an Option: \n");
        printf("1. Request_Production\n");
        printf("2. Stop_Producer\n");
        printf("3. Stop_Scheduler\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        switch( a ) 
        {
            case 1:
                kill(producer_pid, 16);     //Send SIGUSR1 to producer.c
                break;

            case 2:
                kill(producer_pid, 2);      //Send SIGINT to producer.c
                break;

            // Successfully exit program
            case 3:
                return 0;

            // Invalid Choice
            default :
                printf("Invalid choice\n");
        }
    }
}
```

producer.c:

```
/*
 * producer.c
 */

#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n = 1;

void sigusr1(int signo)
{

    printf("Producing %d", n);
    n++;
}


int main()
{


    struct sigaction act;
    sigset_t block_mask;
    sigfillset(&block_mask);
    act.sa_handler = sigusr1;
    act.sa_mask = block_mask;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) == 0){
        printf("success");
    }


    while(1) {

        sleep(2);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me (on Mac OS X 10.7.5):

#### producer.c

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t n = 0;

static void sigusr1(int signo)
{
    n += signo / SIGUSR1;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    sigset_t block_mask;
    sigfillset(&block_mask);
    act.sa_handler = sigusr1;
    act.sa_mask = block_mask;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("success %d\n", (int)getpid());
        while (1)
        {
            pause();
            printf("Producer: %d\n", n);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}
```

#### scheduler.c

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 0; // This variable will be used for the switch later

    // Check to ensure correct number of command line arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s pid\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Grab PID of producer.c
    int producer_pid = atoi(argv[1]);       

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Choose an Option: \n");
        printf("1. Request Production\n");
        printf("2. Stop Producer\n");
        printf("3. Stop Scheduler\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        switch (a) 
        {
            case 1:
                if (kill(producer_pid, SIGUSR1) != 0)
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to send signal %d to %d\n", SIGUSR1, producer_pid);
                break;

            case 2:
                if (kill(producer_pid, SIGTERM) != 0)
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to send signal %d to %d\n", SIGTERM, producer_pid);
                break;

            // Successfully exit program
            case 3:
                return 0;

            // Invalid Choice
            default :
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid choice (%d)\n", a);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Sample output

```
$ (./producer &)
$ success 40119
$ ./scheduler 40119
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
1
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
Producer: 1
1
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
Producer: 2
1
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
Producer: 3
1
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
Producer: 4
1
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
Producer: 5
1
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
Producer: 6
1
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
Producer: 7
1
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
Producer: 8
2
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
1
Failed to send signal 30 to 40119
Choose an Option: 
1. Request Production
2. Stop Producer
3. Stop Scheduler
3
$
```

#### What changed?

Various changes, but the key ones are:

1. **Ensure that output messages end with a newline.**
2. Make `n` into a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable; that's what the C standard says you can access in a signal handler.
3. Have the main loop in the producer `pause()` and then print.  The `pause()` system call only returns when interrupted by a signal.
4. Use symbolic signal names in the scheduler too.
5. **Have the scheduler send `SIGTERM` rather than `SIGINT` to terminate the producer.**  If the producer is run in background, it is ignoring interrupts.
6. Have the scheduler identify when the `kill()` calls fail.
7. Have the producer identify its PID.

I've removed the superfluous headers from the file headings.

The funny `signo / SIGUSR1` in the signal handler avoids warnings about unused arguments; it serves no other purpose.  As shown, the programs compile cleanly under:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition scheduler.c -o scheduler  
gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition producer.c -o producer
```

This is using GCC 4.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

One remark:

There are functions which are safe and others which are not safe to be called from signal handlers.

`printf` may not be called from a signal handler. `write` on the other hand is safe.

The list is specified by POSIX-1, but details may vary between operating systems. For Linux, you will find the list in the signal(7):

http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal

Comment: how would i use write with the int variable n? with the function being called as such `write(int fd, char *buf, int num_bytes)` i don't know where to fit the variable `n` in there...

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, "%d", n); write(fd, buffer, len);` should do. Or some doing your own `sprintf`-like handling of a single integer.

Comment: still not doing anything...i don't think the printf is necessarily the problem

Comment: @midma101 printf is not the problem here, but it is not valid anyway

Comment: @vonbrand sprintf is not allowed in a signal handler as well. Although I don't see a reason why (some implementations may malloc internally...?)